# How do I use Lyft driver API like Mystro android app?

Tags: android, python, ios, node.js, lyft-api

I want to use Lyft Driver api like in the Mystro android app however iv searched everywhere and all I could find is lyft api.
To elaborate more on what I'm trying to achieve, I want api that will allow me to intergrate with the lyft driver app and not the lyft rider app, I want to be able to for example view nearby ride requests as a driver.

The Mystro android app has this feature, how is it done

Comment: If you could find out how it's done, then it would be free, not a 30 day trial, and therefore the app wouldn't have a purpose... You could politely email the app developers and ask. If I had to guess, they have a signed contract with Lyft

Answer (score 1):

The Mystro app does not have any affiliation with either Uber or Lyft nor do they use their APIs to interact with a driver (as neither Uber or Lyft have a publicly accessible driver API like this).  They use an Android Accessibility "feature" that let's the phone look into and interact with other apps you have running.

So basically Mystro uses this accessibility feature (Google has since condemned the use of the accessibility feature like this) to interact with the Uber and Lyft app on the driver's behalf.

Comment: but how it does the same, can you please share any example url or github url ?